# ModuleNotFoundError - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory

New to Python and getting errors when importing modules. I have the following structure (not sure if this is a good way to show folder structure):

- ecommerce

  - customer

    - __init__.py
    - contact.py
  - shopping

    - __init__.py
    - sales.py
- __init__.py

I want to import contact.py from customer into sales.py in shopping but get presented with: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eccommerce'*.

I'm using this:

`from ecommerce.customer import contact` at start of the sales.py file.

Any ideas?

VSCode, MacOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

`from ecommerce.customer import contact` would work if 'customer' was a class in the `ecommerce.py` file, but in your case, those are different files so it doesn't work...

The correct syntax would be:
`from customer import contact`
but you need to adjust those files.

Another way around would be to import os, navigate to that ecommerce folder like so: `os.getcwd('insert dir path here')`, and then import customer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this apply if my ecommerce is a folder and not a .py? Ecommerce, customer and shopping are all folders without the .py extension

Comment: As I said, ecomerce.customer will work only if ecommerce is a python file.. Not a dir. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One thing to pay attention to is where is your current working directory located. If you have the cwd set to be in ecommerce than you should be able to access the contact with the syntax you inputted.

I ran into this issue several times and in the python documentation this setup should technically work, **init** files being parsed by the python parser as individual packages which you can then access. It seems though that it won't work with the standard python interpreter and I haven't found the answer why. One way to get around this is to do as @Sory suggests, at the beginning of your package entry, add the path to the environment variable. This is a work around though and can lead to problems later on.

Another option is to use a separate python interpreter, i use for example the IPython interpreter from Jupyter which runs with this setup perfectly fine. This will give you another external dependency though.

Be sure though that the current working directory is set to be the root folder though as that is usually the first problem.